# How to pass a parent directive attribute value to a child directive scope through transclude?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-template

I am trying to pass an attribute value from a directive to the child directive's scope through ng-transclude. I've tried using =, @, & for the scope binding, however I'm still boggled. I'd like the child directive to inherit the attribute from the parent directive. Any help would be appreciated!

I've made a jsfiddle here --> https://jsfiddle.net/egdfLzLj/5/

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('parent', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        label: '@'
    },
    template: '<section>' +
            '<label>{{::label}}' + 
            '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
            '</label>' +
      '</section>'
  };
});

app.directive('child', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      type: '@',
      label: '&'
    },
    template: '<input ng-type="type" ng-value="::label">'
  };
});
```

Html

```
<parent label="Parent Label">
  <child type="text"></child>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/egdfLzLj/2/**

HTML

```
<parent label="Parent Label">
    <child type="text"></child>
</parent>
```

Directive

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('parent', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        label: '@'
    },
    template: '<section>' +
            '<label>{{::label}}' + 
            '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
            '</label>' +
      '</section>'
  };
})

app.directive('child', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope) {scope.label =  scope.$parent.label;},
    template: '<input type="text" value="{{ label }}">'
  };
});
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to avoid having to add label to the child element. I'd like it to inherit the attribute from the parent. I put in the jsfiddle what I am expecting to be rendered.

Comment: @softvar I was also trying to get the value of te parent with the require key, but it did not work. Parent was not found and so it failed to have the extra parameter in the link function. Why? Is it because the parent transcludes?

Comment: This works, but I think the scope is no longer private. Is there a way to keep the scope private?

Comment: Yes, use: `scope: true,` in child directive which will eventually have its own isolated scope. But then you wont be able to access anything from parent unless you define parentController and use it in child directive's link function. Something like: `link: function (scope, elem, attr, parentController) {// access parentController's scope variables here }`

Comment: Awesome! I'll try that, thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Pleasure to help you! :)